# How to factorize expression $- a^{2} b + a^{2} c + a b^{2} - a c^{2} - b^{2} c + b c^{2}$?

Tags: factoring

I have an expression and I know its factorized form:
$$
- a^{2} b + a^{2} c + a b^{2} - a c^{2} - b^{2} c + b c^{2}=(c-a)(a-b)(b-c)
$$
It's simple algebra, but I'm don't see any way how to factorize the expression in the left side by myself. Seems I missed some algebra lessons :)

I tried factorizing $a,b,c$ terms, but I don't see any way to factorize it further:
$$
a(b^2-c^2)+b(c^2-a^2)+c(a^2-b^2)=a(b-c)(b+c)+b(c-a)(c+a)+c(a-b)(a-b)
$$

Could you help me understand how to think to factorize the expression by myself?

Comment: Write what you tried in your question, otherwise it will be closed very soon and noone will be able to help you.

Comment: I believe there's a typo and the LHS should be $-a^2b+a^2c+ab^2-ac^2-b^2c+bc^2$.

Comment: I think the second-to-last-term is $-b^2c$ not $-c^2c$.

Comment: Considering it first as a quadratic polynomial in $a$, you will soon discover that you can factorize $(b-c).$ And by symmetry, also $(c-a)$ and $(a-b)$ in the remaining factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is one possible approach:

\begin{align*}
-a^{2}b + a^{2}c + ab^{2} - ac^{2} - b^{2}c + bc^{2} & = (ab^{2} - a^{2}b) + (a^{2}c - ac^{2}) + (bc^{2} - b^{2}c)\\\\
& = ab(b - a) + ac(a - c) + bc(c - b)\\\\
& = ab(b - a) + ac((a - b) + (b - c)) + bc(c - b)\\\\
& = (ac - ab)(a - b) + (ac - bc)(b - c)\\\\
& = a(c - b)(a - b) + c(a - b)(b - c)\\\\
& = (a - b)(b - c)(c - a)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the polynomial as follows :

$$
\begin{align}a^2(c-b)-a(c^2-b^2)+bc(c-b)
\end{align}
$$

Since $c-b$ is a common factor, you have :

$$(c-b)\left(a^2-a(b+c)+bc\right)$$

Then recall that [Vieta's formulas  for quadratic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vieta%27s_formulas&action=edit&section=3) polynomial :

$$
\begin{align}&a^2-a(b+c)+bc=0\\
\implies &a_1=b,\quad a_2=c\end{align}
$$

Finally, using by [factor theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) , you get :

$$(c-b)(a-b)(a-c)$$

which completes the answer .

Answer (score 2):

The thing to notice is that when you replace all the $b$s with $a$s, the expression is zero.

Likewise, replacing $b$ with $c$ and $c$ with $a$, the expression is zero.

So by the Factor Theorem, $(a-b)$, $(b-c)$ and $(c-a)$ are all factors.

Since the polynomial is of order $3$, there are no other factors other than these containing $a,b$ and $c$, so it factorises as $$\lambda(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$$

Then the choice of $\lambda$ is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Well, notice that the degrees in the terms on the left hand side count up to three. So, something of the form $(a+b+c)^3$ will be a factorization of it (if it factorizes).

You can also see that the left hand side is symmetric in the sense that if you permute $a,b,c$, you will get the same left hand side (there six permutations on these three letters). Therefore, your factorization should be symmetric as well.

Furthermore, you could try to fill in some simple substitutions, like $a = 2b$ (or $a =b$), to find a zero of the polynomial.